# Android init flash_recovery service

Tags: android, init

In the `init.rc` of my Galaxy-S4 (I9500) there is this code:

```
service flash_recovery /system/etc/install-recovery.sh
    class main
    seclabel u:r:flash_recovery:s0
    oneshot
```

It seems that `/system/etc/install-recovery.sh` will be executed at start-up. I patched it by adding this line:

```
echo $(date) > /data/misc/user/tmp.txt
```

But this line was never executed as don't see the file in `/data/misc/user` folder which has **777** access rights.

I suspect that it is somehow related to the `seclabel u:r:flash_recovery:s0` statement in the `/init.rc` file. But I don't know what is it exactly.

Comment: I had the same problem and finally edited ramdisk to solve adding my own service.

Comment: it confused me so long time..